# How can I get selected area in angular material table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to allow the users to select the area in angular table like excel sheets. Something like in the below image

[image]

I have achieved multi selection rows on click.

[Stackblitz | multi selection rows](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-row-select?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html)

I am  not sure how to proceed.

I found some similar plugins but not sure how to achieve that in Angular

1. [Excel-style Table Cell Selector Plugin With jQuery - TableCellsSelection](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Excel-style-Table-Cell-Selector-Plugin-With-jQuery-TableCellsSelection/)
2. [Table Selection | CKEditor.com](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/table.html#!/guide/dev_table)

Any help , suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create similar plugin for Angular with the help of custom directive.

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/14SYRPU8vOSQsEXEixhn?open=app%2Frange-selection.directive.ts)**

It supports:

- Click - to select cell
- Ctrl + Click - to toggle cell
- Shift + Click to select range
- Click and Drag to select range
- rowSpan and colSpan behavior

**range-selection.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, NgZone, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, pipe, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, switchMap, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: 'table[range-selection]',
})
export class RangeSelectionDirective implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  @Input() selectionClass = 'state--selected';

  selectedRange = new Set<HTMLTableCellElement>();

  private readonly table: HTMLTableElement;

  private startCell: HTMLTableCellElement = null;

  private cellIndices = new Map<HTMLTableCellElement, { row: number; column: number }>();

  private selecting: boolean;

  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private zone: NgZone, {nativeElement}: ElementRef<HTMLTableElement>) {
    this.table = nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.initListeners());
  }

  private initListeners() {
    const withCell = pipe(
      map((event: MouseEvent) => ({event, cell: (event.target as HTMLElement).closest<HTMLTableCellElement>('th,td')})),
      filter(({cell}) => !!cell),
    );
    const mouseDown$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.table, 'mousedown')
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event.button === 0),
        withCell,
        tap(this.startSelection)
      );
    const mouseOver$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.table, 'mouseover');
    const mouseUp$ = fromEvent(document, 'mouseup').pipe(
      tap(() => this.selecting = false)
    );
    this.handleOutsideClick();

    mouseDown$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => mouseOver$.pipe(takeUntil(mouseUp$))),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      withCell
    ).subscribe(this.select);
  }

  private handleOutsideClick() {
    fromEvent(document, 'mouseup').pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe((event: any) => {
      if (!this.selecting && !this.table.contains(event.target as HTMLElement)) {
        this.clearCells();
      }
    });
  }

  private startSelection = ({cell, event}: { event: MouseEvent, cell: HTMLTableCellElement }) => {
    this.updateCellIndices();
    if (!event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey) {
      this.clearCells();
    }

    if (event.shiftKey) {
      this.select({cell});
    }

    this.selecting = true;
    this.startCell = cell;

    if (!event.shiftKey) {
      if (this.selectedRange.has(cell)) {
        this.selectedRange.delete(cell);
      } else {
        this.selectedRange.add(cell);
      }
      cell.classList.toggle(this.selectionClass);
    }
  };

  private select = ({cell}: { cell: HTMLTableCellElement }) => {
    this.clearCells();
    this.getCellsBetween(this.startCell, cell).forEach(item => {
      this.selectedRange.add(item);
      item.classList.add(this.selectionClass);
    });
  };

  private clearCells() {
    Array.from(this.selectedRange).forEach(cell => {
      cell.classList.remove(this.selectionClass);
    });
    this.selectedRange.clear();
  }

  private getCellsBetween(start: HTMLTableCellElement, end: HTMLTableCellElement) {
    const startCoords = this.cellIndices.get(start);
    const endCoords = this.cellIndices.get(end);
    const boundaries = {
      top: Math.min(startCoords.row, endCoords.row),
      right: Math.max(startCoords.column + start.colSpan - 1, endCoords.column + end.colSpan - 1),
      bottom: Math.max(startCoords.row + start.rowSpan - 1, endCoords.row + end.rowSpan - 1),
      left: Math.min(startCoords.column, endCoords.column),
    };

    const cells = [];

    iterateCells(this.table, (cell) => {
      const { column, row } = this.cellIndices.get(cell);
      if (column >= boundaries.left && column <= boundaries.right &&
        row >= boundaries.top && row <= boundaries.bottom) {
        cells.push(cell);
      }
    });

    return cells;
  }

  private updateCellIndices() {
    this.cellIndices.clear();
    const matrix = [];
    iterateCells(this.table, (cell, y, x) => {
      for (; matrix[y] && matrix[y][x]; x++) {}
      for (let spanX = x; spanX < x + cell.colSpan; spanX++) {
        for (let spanY = y; spanY < y + cell.rowSpan; spanY++) {
          (matrix[spanY] = matrix[spanY] || [])[spanX] = 1;
        }
      }
      this.cellIndices.set(cell, {row: y, column: x});
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }
}

function iterateCells(table: HTMLTableElement, callback: (cell: HTMLTableCellElement, y: number, x: number) => void): void {
  for (let y = 0; y < table.rows.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < table.rows[y].cells.length; x++) {
      callback(table.rows[y].cells[x], y, x);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**[Your Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-row-select-7zvp3c?file=styles.css)**

Comment: Perfect. Only confusion is that how can I differentiate the rows ? I checked the selected items but couldn't get the rows details

Comment: You have `selectedRange` which is a set of cells, each cell has a parent which is a row

Comment: I couldn't find any properties in ParentElement using which I can differenciate the rows. I tried  adding unique Id to parent element to differenciate the rows.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-area-selection?file=app%2Frange-selection.directive.ts

Comment: Do you want to get all selected rows?

Comment: Selected cells with info about row. so that I can differentiate those cells based on row

Comment: Try to select something and look at console log https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-area-selection-klmsqg?file=app%2Frange-selection.directive.ts. It should show you list of cells with rowId

Answer (score 3):

But it's not so complex do it [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-row-select-sr1gqu?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts)

If our tds are like

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell #cell  *matCellDef="let element;let i=index" 
    (click)="select($event,cell)"
    <!--use isSelected(i,0) for the first column
            isSelected(i,1) for the second column
            ...
    -->
    [ngClass]="{'selected':isSelected(i,0)}"
    > {{element.position}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

We get the cells using viewChildren, and declare an array with the selection

```
  selection: number[]=[];
  @ViewChildren("cell", { read: ElementRef }) cells: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

In cells we has all the "td" order from top to bottom and from left to rigth

The function select take account if you are pressed the shifh key or the control key

```
  select(event: MouseEvent, cell: any) {
    //search the cell "clicked"
    const cellClick = this.cells.find(x => x.nativeElement == event.target);

    //get the index of this cells
    let indexSelected = -1;
    this.cells.forEach((x, i) => {
      if (x == cellClick) indexSelected = i;
    });

   
    if (event.ctrlKey) { //if ctrl pressed

      if (this.selection.indexOf(indexSelected)>=0) //if its yet selected
        this.selection=this.selection.filter(x=>x!=indexSelected);
      else                                          //if it's not selected
        this.selection.push(indexSelected)
    } else {
      if (event.shiftKey) {    //if the key shift is pressed
        if (this.selection.length)      //if there any more selected
        {

          //calculate the row and col of fisrt element we selected
          let rowFrom=this.selection[0]%this.dataSource.data.length;
          let colFrom=Math.floor(this.selection[0]/this.dataSource.data.length)

          //idem from the index selected
          let rowTo=indexSelected%this.dataSource.data.length;
          let colTo=Math.floor(indexSelected/this.dataSource.data.length)

           //interchange if from is greater than to
          if (rowFrom>rowTo)
            [rowFrom, rowTo] = [rowTo, rowFrom]
          if (colFrom>colTo)
            [colFrom, colTo] = [colTo, colFrom]

          //clean the array
          this.selection=[]

          //we run througth all the td to check if we need push or not
          this.cells.forEach((x,index)=>{
            const row=index%this.dataSource.data.length;
            const col=Math.floor(index/this.dataSource.data.length)
            if (row>=rowFrom && row<=rowTo && col>=colFrom && col<=colTo)
              this.selection.push(index)
          })
        }
        else   //if there're anything selected and the shit is pressed
        this.selection = [indexSelected]
      } else {  //if no key shit nor key ctrl
        this.selection = [indexSelected]
      }
    }
  }
```

And a function isSelected give as posibility to change the class

```
  isSelected(row,column)
  {
    const index=column*this.dataSource.data.length+row
    return this.selection.indexOf(index)>=0
  }
```

with a .css

```
table {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
td { 
  outline: none!important 
}
.selected
{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

**Update**

In the example you need `shift & ctrl`. But we can has a checkbox or a select to "change the way of selection" -use [(ngModel)]- and replace the conditions event.shiftKey and event.ctrlKey.

If you allways select a range  you can use two variables "fromIndex" and "toIndex",

```
fromIndex:number=-1
toIndex:number=-1

select(event: MouseEvent, cell: any){
   ....
  ..get the indexSelected ...
  if (this.fromIndex==-1){ //If nothing select
     this.fromIndex=indexSelected
     this.toIndex=-1
  }
  else{
     this.toIndex=indexSelected;
  }
  if (this.toIndex>=0 && this.fromIndex>=0)
  {
      ...the code to select range
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Is there any way we can select cells without `shift`& `ctrl` key press?  something like this example https://plnkr.co/edit/8wy5oMGEkLi1e9mg?preview

Comment: In the example you need `shift & ctrl`. You can has a checkbox or a select to "change the way of selection" -use [(ngModel)]- and replace the conditions event.shiftKey and event.ctrlKey. If you allways select a range  you can use two variables "fromIndex" and "toIndex", see the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to try some third party libraries which seem to be used by the angular community:

**ag grid:**

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection/

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8wy5oMGEkLi1e9mg) for ag-grid range selection

```
[enableRangeSelection]="true"
```

**primefaces**

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/sections

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesections-demo) for primefaces

Answer (score 1):

Below library offers similar feature but its not free. I am not sure about the alternative libraries

**`SyncFusion :`**

[https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/angular-spreadsheet#:~:text=The%20Angular%20Spreadsheet%20component%20can,Microsoft%20Excel%2097%2D2003%2](https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/angular-spreadsheet#:%7E:text=The%20Angular%20Spreadsheet%20component%20can,Microsoft%20Excel%2097%2D2003%2)

**`SyncFusion | Excel`**

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/?&_ga=2.263488904.50430700.1596175160-2025228585.1595393533#/material/spreadsheet/default

**`StackBlitz | Demo :`**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swdvq9?file=app.component.html